# Functionally related random variables (Klein-Goldberger econometric model)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, reference-request

I've recently been looking at the Klein-Goldberger econometric model, and there's one cryptic line thrown in on page 44 of the monograph that goes as follows: "A theorem of probability theory tells us that if we know the probability distribution of one of two functionally related random variables, we can derive the distribution of the other random variable. This theorem is readily extended to two sets of random variables connected by a system of functional relationships." Which theorem is this and where can I find a proof of it? It's in the context of maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: I think what it means is that, suppose we have two r.v. that are functionally related, for example, $X = Y^2$, knowing the law of either $X$ or $Y$ let's us work out the law of the other. If we let $X$ and $Y$ be random vectors of random variables, i.e. $X = ( X_1, ..., X_n)$, and $Y = (Y_1, ..., Y_n)$, and they're related by some continuous function $X = f(Y)$, then knowing the law of one is enough to work out the law of the other.

Comment: A proof if you require it https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.math.umd.edu/~millson/teaching/STAT400fall18/handouts/changeofvariable.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwifzqStjorzAhWhgf0HHZYCCQwQFnoECDwQAQ&sqi=2&usg=AOvVaw0Bb_JWjtuScyuooA7IOE_3